# Hibernate unable to determine collection owner while deleting from many-to-many relation with TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's start with some context. I had to create separate module with some functionality, it was adding new entities which had many-to-many relation to entity defined in an abstract class. This abstract class was later to be extended in main project with Hiberante TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance. The goal was to delegate as many responibilities to this module in which I could operate on an abstract class.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractClassA {

...
@MappedBy("classAset")
@ManyToMany
private Set<ClassB> classBset = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class ClassB implements Serializable {

...
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "classB_classA_realtion_table",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "classB_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "classA_id")})
private Set<AbstractClassA> classAset = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Most of it worked fine, the abstract class had some other relations (one-to-many) and there was no problems. I was also able to delete objects of ClassB without obstacles and faced issue only while trying to delete objects of a concreteClass extending said abstract class as I got error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Unable to determine collection owner identifier for orphan-delete processing
```

I tried searching for answers but I couldn't find one that included many-to-many relation, all of them said about one-to-many and using orphanRemoval=true which is not possible here. I also tried experimenting with mappedBy but nothing seem to work.

As a last resort I removed the abstract class and made direct many-to-many relation with concreteClass extending it and that seemed to help. But that solution was contradicting the idea of moving functionality into separate module as now it had dependency to concreteClass.

I wonder is there something I'm missing in how I defined my relation or was my approach with using abstract class wrong from the beginning?